# Trouble Getting Function to Write the Desired Output

Tags: python, csv, file-writing

Q: "Write a function named "internet_histogram" that takes no parameters and does not return a value. There will be a file named "survey.csv" in the testing environment containing survey results as described above (the file has a header line which much be addressed by your code). Write a new file named "histogram.csv" containing 2 columns representing "internet_use,frequency" and no header line that will contain a histogram of the results of responders ages 30 to 33 including the endpoint ages. Your file will have exactly 6 lines with internet_use values of 1-5 corresponding to the intfreq results and 6 for responders who answered 2 to eminuse. Read the survey results file and track how many responders in this age range answered with each of these 6 options and write these counts to your "histogram.csv" file in order of internet_use starting with 1.

Example `histogram.csv`:

```
1,5
2,7
3,0
4,1
5,2
6,4
```

Here is my code for this:

```
def internet_histogram():
    count_6 = 0
    count_5 = 0
    count_4 = 0
    count_3 = 0
    count_2 = 0
    count_1 = 0
    with open("survey.csv",'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        with open("histogram.csv", 'w') as g:
            writer = csv.writer(g)
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                if int(line[3]) >= 29 and int(line[3]) <= 53:
                    if line[2] != '':
                        if int(line[2]) == 1:
                            count_1 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 2:
                            count_2 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 3:
                            count_3 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 4:
                            count_4 += 1
                        elif int(line[2]) == 5:
                            count_5 += 1
                        else:
                            count_6 += 1
            arr = [[1, count_1], [2, count_2], [3, count_3], [4, count_4], [5, count_5], [6, count_6]]
            for i in arr:
                writer.writerow(i)
```

Here are my results vs. expected results when the code is ran:

```
**wrote**:
1,236
2,329
3,42
4,34
5,17
6,0

**expected**:
1,48
2,48
3,7
4,6
5,1
6,3
```

What is preventing this function from delivering the expected results? What changes could I make? Thank you in advance for your help:)

('survey.csv' file available in this dataset for reference, if needed: http://www.pewinternet.org/dataset/jan-3-10-2018-core-trends-survey/)

Comment: Can you put sample input in the question please

Comment: sure, here's one of the ones it gave me when i ran it:

        survey.csv
        eminuse,intmob,intfreq,age
        1,1,1,68
        1,1,2,29
        1,1,1,99
        1,1,2,35
        1,1,2,57
        1,1,2,30
        1,1,2,26
        1,1,2,65
        1,1,2,47
        1,1,4,43
        1,1,2,40
        1,1,2,60
        1,1,1,30
        1,1,4,25
        1,1,5,60
        2,2,,53
        1,1,2,37
        1,1,2,60
        1,1,2,56
        1,1,2,66
        2,2,,40
        1,1,2,61
        1,1,1,68
        1,1,2,39
        1,1,2,66
        [file truncated for display]

Comment: sorry i tried to format that into a code block but i was having trouble :(

Comment: Question says `... responders ages 30 to 33 ...`. But your code checks for `if int(line[3]) >= 29 and int(line[3]) <= 53:`

Answer (score 1):

```
def internet_histogram():
count_6 = 0
count_5 = 0
count_4 = 0
count_3 = 0
count_2 = 0
count_1 = 0
with open("survey.csv",'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open("histogram.csv", 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        next(reader)
        for line in reader:
            if int(line[3]) >= 31 and int(line[3]) <= 47:
                if int(line[0]) == 2:
                    count_6 +=1
                if line[2] != '':
                    if int(line[2]) == 1:
                        count_1 += 1
                    elif int(line[2]) == 2:
                        count_2 += 1
                    elif int(line[2]) == 3:
                        count_3 += 1
                    elif int(line[2]) == 4:
                        count_4 += 1
                    elif int(line[2]) == 5:
                        count_5 += 1
        arr = [[1, count_1], [2, count_2], [3, count_3], [4, count_4], [5, count_5], [6, count_6]]
        for i in arr:
            writer.writerow(i)
```

your code should look like this, your age range was wrong and the count_6 was calculated inncorrectly.

Comment: sorry change the 31  to a 30 and the 47 to a 33. I used my code for my answer